# Upload picture webroot path in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, file-upload, upload

```
public static string UpdateFile(this IFormFile file, string imgUrl, string envPath, string folderName) 
{
        string fileName = file.FileName;
        
        if (fileName.Length > 64)
        {
            fileName = fileName.Substring(fileName.Length - 64);
        }

        fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + fileName;

        string path = envPath + folderName + fileName;

        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
        {
            file.CopyTo(stream);
        }

        return fileName;
}
```

Is it true for getting path of picture.

I would like to know is true for write in ASP.NET MVC how can I write for check the type and length to wrote here?

Comment: It is true to get the path of picture. Just be sure you need set the correct value when call this static class: `UpdateFile(file, "url","path\", "name\")`, remember add the backslash '\'.  For how to check the length, you get the length correctly in your code, just compare the size you want. For how to check the type, you can get the type by:`Path.GetExtension(fileName).ToLower()`.